# Setting $scope variables AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i am having an issue with adding a variable to the $scope after an event.
Here is the HTML for the select box. Basically when it is changed i need the scope to change.

**`Index.html`**

```
<select ng-controller="ClientCtrl" ng-model="name" 
ng-options="v.name for (k, v) in client" ng-change="selectChange(name)">
</select>

<h2>{{cName}}</h2>
<p>Age: {{cAge}}</p>
<p>Notes: {{cNotes}}</p>
```

**`Controller.js`**

```
$scope.selectChange = function(name){
    $scope.cName = name.name;
    $scope.cAge = name.age;
    $scope.cNotes = name.notes;
  };
```

I have tried a few things to get those variable set. Obviously this one above, then this one:

```
$scope.selectChange = function(name){
        $scope.cName = name.name;
        $scope.cAge = name.age;
        $scope.cNotes = name.notes;
        $scope.$apply();
  };
```

I still don't quite understand apply but i thought i'd give it a try. Any help would be awesome, just need a pointer to wrap my head around why this wouldnt work.

I can get the variables to post to the console.log(cName); but it won't show up when i have the {{cName}}

Comment: [This was also an issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207099/angularjs-multiple-controllers-on-one-page) that was answered by @StenMuchow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually dont have to pass in the name in the ng-change event, since you actually already have that in the scope. The changeEvent can the use $scope.name directly instead of passing it as a parameter.

```
ng-change="selectChange()"
```

**js**

```
$scope.selectChange = function(){
    $scope.cName = $scope.name.name;
    and so on.  
};
```

id suggest you give it a better name than name, i guess were talking about a person, so it would be easier to read if you call it Person.Name and so on;)

You also need to wrap your print within the same controller as you now have name in, to make it work, since the scope gets created for the controller.

Comment: Alright so i applied this and it fixed things up great! I definitely should have thought of that, i was following a change function i found somewhere else but now that you say that it makes more sense to do it this way. Here is a plunker with this working. Thanks! :D [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/nkp6dNuzFlpH4ZDDfbuL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Without more info its hard to debug completely, but from what i can see i would recommend wrapping the entire piece of html in the controller ClientCtrl or else the h2 and p tags wont have access to the scope that it creates.

```
<div ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
  <select ng-model="name" ng-options="v.name for (k, v) in client" ng-change="selectChange(name)">
  </select>

  <h2>{{cName}}</h2>
  <p>Age: {{cAge}}</p>
  <p>Notes: {{cNotes}}</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps otherwise post more info or use a plunker...

Comment: I have the h2 and p's in the ng-view with the ClientCtrl on them but i definitely should have depicted that in my question. I displayed it the way you stated in the plunker for clarification, thanks!